# Getting error while extracting the data from webpage

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've formulated the following code to retrieve data from the webpage provided: https://www.redfin.com/NV/Fallon/630-Serpa-Pl-89406/unit-Fallon/home/178255574?utm_source=android_share&utm_medium=share&utm_nooverride=1&utm_content=link&2010988919=variant&utm_campaign=homecard_share.

However, I'm encountering an 'object required' error at the line:
sqFt = html.getElementsByClassName("statsLabel")(0).NextSibling.getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(0).innerText.

I'm hopeful that someone can offer assistance to rectify this issue, enabling the code to successfully extract the pertinent information from the webpage.

Your guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub ExtractingRedfin()
    Dim url As String
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim html As Object
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' URL of the webpage to scrape
    url = Sheet1.Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value
    
    ' Create a new Internet Explorer instance
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False ' Set to True if you want to see the browser
    
    ' Navigate to the URL
    ie.navigate url
    
    ' Wait for the browser to finish loading the page
    Do While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ' Get the HTML content of the page
    Set html = ie.document
    
    Dim beds As String
    Dim baths As String
    Dim sqFt As String
    Dim price As String
    Dim est As String
    Dim address As String
    Dim cityStateZip As String
    
    beds = html.getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(0).innerText
    baths = html.getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(1).innerText
    sqFt = html.getElementsByClassName("statsLabel")(0).NextSibling.getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(0).innerText
    price = html.getElementsByClassName("info-block price")(0).getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(0).innerText
    est = html.getElementsByClassName("info-block price")(0).getElementsByClassName("statsLabel")(0).innerText
    address = html.getElementsByClassName("street-address")(0).innerText
    cityStateZip = html.getElementsByClassName("citystatezip")(0).innerText
    

    ie.Quit
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Value = beds
    ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = baths
    ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = sqFt
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Value = price
    ws.Cells(2, 5).Value = est
    ws.Cells(2, 6).Value = address
    ws.Cells(2, 7).Value = cityStateZip
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear the website has been restructured since your code last ran successfully. Try replacing the relevant lines with

```
beds = html.getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(1).innerText
baths = html.getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(2).innerText
sqFt = html.getElementsByClassName("stat-block sqft-section")(0).getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(0).innerText
price = html.getElementsByClassName("stat-block beds-section")(0).getElementsByClassName("statsValue")(0).innerText
est = html.getElementsByClassName("stat-block beds-section")(0).getElementsByClassName("est-monthly-payment")(0).innerText
address = html.getElementsByClassName("street-address")(0).innerText
cityStateZip = html.getElementsByClassName("dp-subtext bp-cityStateZip")(0).innerText
```

... while this works just now, naturally there is no guarantee how long this will work (if the website is restructured again) .

If you are interested, read more here [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) and here [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752641(v=vs.85)).

Comment: I got you! thank you so much